# What is the difference between critical points in calculus and critical points in inequality?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

In our school textbook there is a chapter called "Linear Inequalities" which states that critical points are those points where the rational fraction is either 0 or undefined.

But "calculus" chapter states that critical points are those points where the derivative of the function is either 0 or undefined.

Please clarify this. This has created a lot of confusion in my mind.

Comment: In the grand scheme of things the two concepts are unrelated, or too loosely related to bother, and I would even question the soundness of your definition in the context of calculus, but if we just take the definitions for what they mean, the book seems to call "critical" a point which is either outside the domain of a function or where the function is $0$, and in that sense you are looking at "critial points" of a rational function versus "critical points" of the derivative of a function.

Answer (score 0):

The critical points for the derivative of a function *are* the critical points for the inequality $f'(x) >0$  (or, if you like, $f'(x) <0.$)  For rational functions, you want to know where the graph crosses the $x$-axis.   The critical points for a function in calculus are the points where the derivative crosses the $x$-axis or is undefined.